# Efficient method to adjust column values where equal to x - Python

Tags: python, pandas

The following multiplies all values in a column where rows are equal to a specific value. Using below, where row is in `Item` is equal to `Up`, I want to multiply all other columns by `2`. I'm passing this to a single column at at time. Is there a more efficient way to process this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Item' : ['Up','Up','Down','Up','Down','Up'],                  
   'A' : [50, 50, 60, 60, 40, 30], 
   'B' : [60, 70, 60, 50, 50, 60],                         
       })

df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Up', 'A'] = df['A'] * 2
df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Up', 'B'] = df['B'] * 2
```

Out:

```
   Item    A    B
0    Up  100  120
1    Up  100  140
2  Down   60   60
3    Up  120  100
4  Down   40   50
5    Up   60  120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Up', ['A','B']] *= 2
```

Output:

```
   Item    A    B
0    Up  100  120
1    Up  100  140
2  Down   60   60
3    Up  120  100
4  Down   40   50
5    Up   60  120
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I had numerous columns, I'd pass those to a list beforehand and then into the subset?

Comment: Yes, like `list_col = ['A','B','C']; df.loc[some_cond, list_cols] *= 2`.